# MDBG debugging - how to check value of static variable

Tags: mdbg

I am using MDBG to debug running process, but i don't know how to check a value of static variable. Is there some way to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MDbg can capture "local" variables - I assume this means staic as well. If the variable is associated with a stack frame, you can get the value using the GetActiveLocalVars function.

```
MDbgThread t = proc.Threads.Active;
MDbgFrame f=t.CurrentFrame;
foreach (MDbgValue v in f.Function.GetActiveLocalVars(f))
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(v.Name);
                                    Console.WriteLine(v.Value);
                                }
```